# Is one span inside another span? Are they equal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying for an exam, and one of the practice problems is asking:

Is the span <(1,1,-1),(1,0,1)> inside of the span <(-1,1,0),(2,1,1)>? Are they equal?

I think the answer has something to do with linear dependence, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice that both sets are LI, so the dimension of both their spans is 2. That means that the only possibility is that they are equal (one cannot contain the other without the other containing the one). If this is the case, then $(-1,1,0)$ (just picked on of the vectors) is in the span of the other set, so
$$
(-1,1,0) = a_1(1,1,-1) + a_2(1,0,1)
$$
for some $a_1$ and $a_2$. But, when we try to solve for these constants, we find there is no solution, so $(-1,1,0)$ is not in the span of the first set. It follows that neither span is in the other span.

Comment: How did you get their spans are 2?

Comment: there are two linearly independent vectors in each set, so each set has dimension 2 (you can use the set as a basis for the span).

Comment: Just determine the dimension of the span of all four vectors.  No need to solve a system of equations here.

Comment: To determine the span of the 4 vectors you still need to check the linear dependence/independence of the vectors, so it still comes down to the same thing.